# How to use more than one model in a CakePHP controller

Tags: cakephp, model, controller

I have created a registration form and I send data to the controller.

I want to insert this data to 3 different tables (models).

How can this be achieved?

Comment: ^^ -1 Using stored procedures for data manipulation is very very wrong. You should not do business logic in the persistence layer. I know there are tons of legacy apps implemented fully in SQL, but that's just plain wrong. DB is just a repository, use it as one.

Comment: The question is CakePHP related, so stored procedures don't apply as you can include logic -- even complex logic -- in your Models. the *M* part of MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your forms are formatted according to the CakePHP conventions and the relations between the Models will be set up correctly, this will be done automatically when you invoke `$this->Model->save($this->data)`.

Answer (score 19):

What you mean (in CakePHP terms) is that you want to **use** more models than the default one. the default model is the one named like your controller.

To achieve what you want you just declare a variable `$uses` in your controller. It's done like this:

```
<?php
class ExampleController extends AppController {
    var $name = 'Example';

    // $uses is where you specify which models this controller uses
    var $uses = array('Model1', 'Model2', 'ModelN');

    // ... here go your controller actions (methods)

}
?>
```

This will allow your controller to make use of `Model1`, `Model2` and `ModelN`. Rename those and add more according to your needs.

If you do not wish to use models in your controller, you can assign `$uses` to an empty array, i.e.:

```
var $uses = array();
```

Take a look at the corresponding CakePHP book chapters according to the version you're using:

- [**Cake v1.3 "Components helpers and users"**](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Controllers.html#components-helpers-and-uses), and
- [**Cake v2.0 `controller::$uses`**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller%3a%3a%24uses)

Answer (score 0):

This is actually best to loade the model on the fly as that way you don't load it for all methods that you may not need.

```
$this->loadModel('Model1');
```

Way more efficient.

I'd also recommend making sure these tables aren't linked.  If they are then its best to chain them through via:

```
$this->Model1->Model2->find();
```

This is the beginning of teaching you to be more efficient with tables via Containable and Relationships (HasMany, BelongsTo, HABTM)